# How to apply custom logic inside an aggregate function

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently learning Spark and let's say we have the following DataFrame

| user_id | activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | liked |
| 2 | comment |
| 1 | liked |
| 1 | liked |
| 1 | comment |
| 2 | liked |

Each type of activity has its own weight which is used to calculate the score

| activity | weight |
| --- | --- |
| liked | 1 |
| comment | 3 |

And this is the desired output

| user_id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 |

The calculation of score involves counting how many times an event occurred followed by their weight. For instance, user 1 perform 3 likes and a comment, so the weight is given by

```
(3 * 1) + (1 * 3)
```

How do we do this calculation in Spark?

My initial attempt is below

```
val df1 = evidenceDF
      .groupBy("user_id")
      .agg(collect_set("event") as "event_ids")
```

but I got stuck on the mapping portion. What I want to achieve is after I aggregated the events into its `event_ids` field, I'm going to split them and do the calculation in a map function, but I'm having difficulty moving further.

I searched about using a custom aggregator function but it sounds complicated, is there a straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join with the weights dataframe the group by and sum weights :

```
val df1 = evidenceDF.join(df_weight, Seq("activity"))
  .groupBy("user_id")
  .agg(
    sum(col("weight")).as("score")
  )

df1.show

//+-------+-----+
//|user_id|score|
//+-------+-----+
//|      1|    6|
//|      2|    4|
//+-------+-----+
```

Or if actually you have only 2 categories then using `when` expression directly in the `sum` :

```
val df1 = evidenceDF.groupBy("user_id")
  .agg(
    sum(
      when(col("activity") === "liked", 1)
        .when(col("activity") === "comment", 3)
    ).as("score")
  )
```